# How to get dates from database and check if they overlaps?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, date, overlap

I have a sqlite database in which I store all events. I store `StartTime` and `EndTime` against each events in date format.

I have fragments for days with tabs and one activity which adds events. Events are shown in another fragments.

Now I want to check if events do overlap with each other and based on which app should display a message.

How to display message in added event activity when the user saves events.

How can I do this?

I have tried this way but still events get added with same start time and end time:

```java
ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imgbtn_fab);
imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        eventTitle = title.getText().toString();
        EventTableHelper db = new EventTableHelper(getApplication());
        List<EventData> events;
        events = db.getAllEvents();

        for (EventData eventData : events) {

            String datefrom = eventData.getFromDate();

            String[] times = datefrom.substring(11, 16).split(":");
            minutesFrom = Integer.parseInt(times[0]) * 60 + Integer.parseInt(times[1]);

            String dateTo = eventData.getToDate();

            //times = dateTo.substring(11,16).split(":");
            String[] times1 = dateTo.substring(11, 16).split(":");
            minutesTo = Integer.parseInt(times1[0]) * 60 + Integer.parseInt(times1[1]);
        }

        if (eventTitle.length() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Title can not be empty.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else if(minutesFrom == minutesTo) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Event with same time exists.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else
        {
            db.addEvent(new EventData(eventTitle, startTime, endTime, dayOfWeek, location));
            setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
            finish();
        }
    }
});
```

I get dates like this:

```java
c = Calendar.getInstance();

year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm a");
datefrom = c.getTime();
startTime = String.valueOf(datefrom);

aTime = df.format(datefrom.getTime());
showFromTime.setText(aTime);

c.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 1);
dateto = c.getTime();
endTime = String.valueOf(dateto);

bTime = df.format(dateto.getTime());
showToTime.setText(bTime);
```

I have created an `EventTableHelper`:

```java
public class EventTableHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String TABLE = "event";
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    private static final String KEY_FROM_DATE = "datefrom";
    private static final String KEY_TO_DATE = "dateto";
    private static final String KEY_LOCATION = "location";
    private static final String KEY_DAY_OF_WEEK = "dayofweek";

    public EventTableHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, Constants.DATABASE_NAME, null, Constants.DATABASE_VERSION);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    }

    public void createTable(SQLiteDatabase db){
        String CREATE_EVENTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE+ "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
                + KEY_TITLE + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_FROM_DATE + " DATE,"
                + KEY_TO_DATE + " DATE,"
                + KEY_DAY_OF_WEEK + " TEXT "
                + KEY_LOCATION + " TEXT" +  ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_EVENTS_TABLE);
    }
    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE);

       // createTable(db);
       // onCreate(db);
    }

    public void addEvent(EventData event) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_TITLE,event.getTitle());
        values.put(KEY_FROM_DATE, event.getFromDate());
        values.put(KEY_TO_DATE,event.getToDate());
        values.put(KEY_DAY_OF_WEEK,event.getDayOfWeek());
        values.put(KEY_LOCATION,event.getLocation());

        db.insert(TABLE, null, values);

        db.close();
    }

   EventData getEvent(int id) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        EventData eventData = new EventData();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE, new String[]{KEY_ID,
                        KEY_TITLE, KEY_FROM_DATE, KEY_TO_DATE, KEY_LOCATION}, KEY_ID + "=?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(id)}, null, null, null, null);

       if( cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst() ) {
          eventData = new EventData(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2),
                   cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4));

       }
       return eventData;
    }

    public List<EventData> getAllEvents() {
        List<EventData> conList = new ArrayList<EventData>();

        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {

                EventData event = new EventData();

                event.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                event.setTitle(cursor.getString(1));
                event.setFromDate(cursor.getString(2));
                event.setToDate(cursor.getString(3));
                event.setLocation(cursor.getString(4));

                conList.add(event);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        return conList;
    }
}
```

I tried to use getAll events function in an activity to get data.

Edit: Here's my current code.

```java
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    eventTitle = title.getText().toString();
    EventTableHelper db = new EventTableHelper(getApplication());
    List<EventData> events;
    // events = db.getOverlappingEvents(startTime,endTime);

    if (eventTitle.length() == 0) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Title can not be empty.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else if(db.doesEventOverlap(startTime,endTime))
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Event exists", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else
    {
        db.addEvent(new EventData(eventTitle, startTime, endTime, dayOfWeek, location));
        setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: @shmosel : Please check the code if it is right.

Comment: @Sid, please check code if it is right! If not, then give us the input, expected output, the actual output, and if there were then all the error messages

Comment: I am not getting any output from this. The expected result is if start time and end time of the new creating event matches with the previous events start time and end time in the database it should show msg that the event with same time already exists. Thank you, @Gavriel

Comment: what is db? Why don't you query the db so that you only get the dates you need to display?

Comment: Input is time from time picker in date format I have given code for that.

Comment: Please check edited question. @Gavriel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

minutesTo, minutesFrom will only have the value for the last line in the db.

I would try to do a new function in EventTableHelper:

```
List<EventData> getOverlappingEvents(Date startTime, Date endTime) {
    List<EventData> conList = new ArrayList<EventData>();

    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE
      + " WHERE (" + KEY_FROM_DATE + " < '" + startTime
      + "' AND '" + startTime + "' < " + KEY_TO_DATE + ") OR "
      + " (" + KEY_FROM_DATE + " < '" + endTime
      + "' AND '" + endTime + "' < " + KEY_TO_DATE + ") OR "

      + " (" + KEY_FROM_DATE + " < '" + startTime
      + "' AND '" + endTime + "' < " + KEY_TO_DATE + ") OR "
      + " ('" + startTime + "' < " + KEY_FROM_DATE
      + " AND " + KEY_TO_DATE + " < '" + endTime + "')";

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {

            EventData event = new EventData();

            event.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            event.setTitle(cursor.getString(1));
            event.setFromDate(cursor.getString(2));
            event.setToDate(cursor.getString(3));
            event.setLocation(cursor.getString(4));

            conList.add(event);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return conList;
}
```

and in onClick:

```
events = db.getOverlappingEvents();
...
```

and instead of:

```
else if(minutesFrom == minutesTo)
```

this:

```
else if(events.size() > 0)
```

Actually it could be even further optimized, because it looks like you don't need the overlapping events data, only a boolean if there's at least one overlapping event:

```
boolean doesEventOverlap(Date startTime, Date endTime) {
    String selectQuery = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + TABLE
      + " WHERE (" + KEY_FROM_DATE + " < '" + startTime
      + "' AND '" + startTime + "' < " + KEY_TO_DATE + ") OR "
      + " (" + KEY_FROM_DATE + " < '" + endTime
      + "' AND '" + endTime + "' < " + KEY_TO_DATE + ") OR "

      + " (" + KEY_FROM_DATE + " < '" + startTime
      + "' AND '" + endTime + "' < " + KEY_TO_DATE + ") OR "
      + " ('" + startTime + "' < " + KEY_FROM_DATE
      + " AND " + KEY_TO_DATE + " < '" + endTime + "')";

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            EventData event = new EventData();
            return cursor.getInt(0) > 0;
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return false;
}
```

and in onClick instead of:

```
else if(minutesFrom == minutesTo)
```

this:

```
else if(db.doesEventOverlap())
```

Comment: hey, this function is checking overlapping events for all the days. How can I check overlapping events for each day in a week? @Gavriel

Comment: No, this function as it's name and the parameters' name suggest if an event with the given startTime, endTime overlaps any event in the DB. I don't even understand what do you mean on "all the days" and "each day in a week"

Comment: As I have fragments for days. I am adding events for each day and it shows in each fragment. So I want to check for the event which overlaps for each day. For now if i am adding an event on monday and if it exists on sunday at same time so it dose not allow to add event at same time on monday. I want to add events for all days. @Gavriel

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Can you open a new question with this new problem? Don't forget to include the code you use (especially parts that you changed since you asked this question) and some examples that make it clear what is your intention.